# Using Java Profiler (VisualVM) with Oracle Application Server (OAS)

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, profiling, visualvm

I need to optimize JSF application. It's running on a localhost Oracle Application Server 10g (OAS).

I would like to use VisualVM to profile the said application but it couldn't detect the instance of OAS.

Do have links or tutorials on how to connect VisualVM with OAS 10g?

Comment: VisualVM can see local applications running under the same user as VisualVM. Do you run VisualVM and OAS under the same user?

Comment: Does "the same user" means "the same instance of JRE"?

Comment: No, it is the same user from the operation system point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Alternativly you can try Netbeans profiler.
You can profile your web/standalone applications using netbeans profiler.

We are uning netbeans profiler to profiling in our applications. Nice tool for profiling the java applications.

Check it out.

https://profiler.netbeans.org/

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqProfilerAttachRemoteServer

Comment: I think the Profiler in Netbeans and VisualVM are the same.